# 2D Fourier transform of $1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I have trouble dealing with the confirm of following relationship:

$$
\mathscr{F}({\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2}}
$$
I have tried transforming to the polar coordinate or using some limit trick.Can anybody help me?Please.

Comment: Polar is promising. The usual "trick" is to have $k$ point along the $x$ axis so that $(x,y)\cdot(k_1,k_2)= \vert (x,y)\vert\vert(k_1,k_2)\vert\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be a function homogeneous of degree $d$ in an $n$-dimensional space. Then its Fourier transform is also homogeneous, but of degree $-(n+d)$:
$$
\hat{f}(c\xi)
= \int f(x) e^{-ix\cdot c\xi} \, dx
= \int f(x) e^{-icx\cdot \xi} \, dx
= \int f(y/c) e^{-iy\cdot \xi} \, |c|^{-n} dy
\\
= \int c^{-d} f(y) e^{-iy\cdot \xi} \, |c|^{-n} dy
= c^{-(n+d)} \int f(y) e^{-iy\cdot \xi} \, dy
= c^{-(n+d)} \hat{f}(\xi).
$$

With $n=2$ and $d=-1,$ which is your case, we get
$$
\hat{f}(c\xi)
= c^{-1} \hat{f}(\xi)
$$
implying that $\hat{f}(\xi) = C|\xi|^{-1}.$ This verifies your relationship modulo the value of the constant $C$.

Comment: Appreciate for this， I have got a more concrete proof, but this abstract one is more beautiful.